# Network density vs connectivity

Tags: graphs

I was reading [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3101653/) where they mention about undirected networks:

> "The total connectivity of a network is defined as
>   $C=\frac{E}{N(N-1)}$ where E is the number of edges and N the total
>   number of nodes."

However, this is just another way of talking about network density is it not? You could just change the denominator and refer to network density for directed and undirected networks.

Or is this "total connectivity" anything different than density?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: Thanks @dkaeae, it didn't occur to me. I fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $C$ here is the density of (simple) directed graphs. You can see the [Wikipedia entry on dense graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph) for more details. In this context, total connectivity is just another name for density.